# stream writer not writing trimmed text to the file in C#

Tags: c#, stream

I have a strange problem. I am getting a stream of text from a tcp client and writing it to a file. The stream is not fully filled hence while converting it to string the unfilled parts of the byte array are converted to \0 so i finally end up having,

```
str = "blah foo bar \0\0\0\0\0...";
```

so what i did is

```
str = str.trim('\0');
```

But if i do this then the string is not getting written to a file using stream writer. If i comment the trim line then its getting written along with all the white space characters. Here is my full code

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("c:\\a\\ta.txt");
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        NetworkStream ns = tc.GetStream();
        byte[] instream = new byte[tc.ReceiveBufferSize];
        Thread.Sleep(2500);
        ns.Read(instream, 0, tc.ReceiveBufferSize);
        string decodedData = string.Empty;
        decodedData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(instream);
        decodedData = decodedData.Trim('\0');
        //string a = "dfdsfdsfdsfdsf";
        //string b = a.Trim('\0');

        try
        {
            sw.Write(decodedData);
            //MessageBox.Show(decodedData);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Can some one explain me why this is and how i can solve htis out.

oh on debugging i can see that decodedData has the trimmed text neat and clean but i dont know why its not being written to the file.

Comment: Loop forever on purpose?

Comment: yes, the device to which this app connects keep sending continuos stream of data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three problems here.

First, you grab the text *from the whole array*, regardless of how many bytes you actually did receive. Most likely this is the source of your zero characters.

To fix that, change the code as follows:

```
int actuallyRead = ns.Read(instream, 0, tc.ReceiveBufferSize);
string decodedData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(instream, 0, actuallyRead);
```

Secondly, you need to close the stream in order for it to flush its contents. The best way to do that is to wrap it in a `using` block:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("c:\\a\\ta.txt"))
{
    ... rest of your code here
}
```

Thirdly, the code would normally never complete. Add a way for it to complete without relying on exception handling, for instance:

```
int actuallyRead = ns.Read(instream, 0, tc.ReceiveBufferSize);
if (actuallyRead == 0)
    break;
string decodedData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(instream, 0, actuallyRead);
```

Comment: The streamwriter seems like so much to do so i just used file.appendalltext which does everything i n a single line

Answer (score 3):

You're never flushing the writer - I suspect everything's just buffered. You should use a `using` statement for your `StreamWriter`, so that it gets disposed when you leave the block. That will then flush the file.

You should *also* look at the value returned from `Stream.Read`, and only create a string using the portion of the buffer which has actually been read.

Finally, it's not clear how you expect this to terminate, given that you've got a `while(true)` loop. You're currently only going to terminate when you get an exception. You should probably terminate if `ns.Read` returns 0.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
decodedData = new string(decodedData.ToCharArray());
```

IIRC, the string constructor will trim trailing NULL terminators.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried...

```
 decodedData = decodedData.Trim(@"\0");
```